# How to have syntax highlighting of input text in Node.js REPL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax-highlighting, read-eval-print-loop, ansi-escape

This is possible in Linux terminal because there is shell like [fish](http://fishshell.com/) that use different highlighting for input text. Is it possible to have something like this in Node.js. Or do I need to reimplement readLine library with this feature.

Does anyone know how to do this in Node.js? I was checking the code for [fish on GitHub](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell) and it seems that the project use NCurses. Can I do the same in Node.js to have REPL where input text is in color?

*EDIT*:

I've tested this code from @MehdiBelbal solution:

```
var readline = require('readline');

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question("lips> ", function(code) {
  console.log('\ncode is ' + code);
  rl.close();
});

rl._writeToOutput = function _writeToOutput(stringToWrite) {
    rl.output.write(stringToWrite.replace(/define/g, '\u001b[1;34mdefine\x1b[0m'));
};
```

but it don't highlight the word define after you type it, you need to type space (or any character) and delete it with backspace.

Comment: That cant be done. Because: your program cant control the terminal or what the user is typing. you can style the terminal to use diffrent colors but thats all.

Comment: of course you can 

https://repl.it/@belbalMehdi/Color-console#index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can acheive this by overriding _writeToOutput method
The '\x1b[31m' is the console red color unicode
you need to add '\x1b[0m' is the reset,
it is necessary for the colors to stop at this position:

```
rl._writeToOutput = function _writeToOutput(stringToWrite) {
    rl.output.write('\x1b[31m'+stringToWrite+'\x1b[0m');
};
```

colors unicodes:

```
Black: \u001b[30m.
Red: \u001b[31m.
Green: \u001b[32m.
Yellow: \u001b[33m.
Blue: \u001b[34m.
Magenta: \u001b[35m.
Cyan: \u001b[36m.
White: \u001b[37m.
```

code example:

```
var readline = require('readline');

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question("code: ", function(code) {
  console.log('\ncode is ' + code);
  rl.close();
});

// force trigger of _writeToOutput on each keystroke
process.stdin.on('keypress', (c, k) => {
    // setTimeout is needed otherwise if you call console.log
    // it will include the prompt in the output
    setTimeout(() => {
        rl._refreshLine();
    }, 0);
});

rl._writeToOutput = function _writeToOutput(stringToWrite) {
    rl.output.write(stringToWrite.replace(/define/g, '\u001b[1;34mdefine\x1b[0m'));
};
```

type "define" to have it in blue.

Comment: I want to style the input not the output.

Comment: yeah the code above styles the user input (written by the user) try it for yourself.
the name of the function is misleading writeToOutput means the readline write the user keystroke to the console otherwise you wont see what you are typing (like passwords write nothing or *****)

Comment: I want to color the text that user is editing not the output. You sent to output `rl.output.write` is output not `rl.input`.

Comment: Yeah i understand your need the function above colors the user input (while editing)

Comment: Ok, will check, so this is some kind of undocumented feature of readline?

Comment: i added an example in my response i use the lts node version

Comment: it's not exactly responsive `rl.output.write(stringToWrite.replace(/define/g, '\u001b[1;34mdefine\x1b[0m'));` this works only when I type define type space and use backspace.

Comment: weird, it works fine for me, try the code i added above

Comment: The problem is that it don't executed on each keypress. So I can't use it for syntax highlighting.

Comment: have you tried the code example i juste added above ? if so on which node version ? so i can reproduce your test

Comment: I've tested your code but it's not what I need, I need syntax highlighting when user is typing. Check my edit.

Comment: ah i see you changed the original question to how to highligh a word in a middle of the input right ?

Comment: it works when I've added `process.stdin.on('keypress', (c, k) => { rl._refreshLine(); });` another undocumented function found in node.js source code, you can add this and I will accept.

Comment: I should write Syntax highlighting, this is what I meant when I written highlighting. So it update words while user is typing.

Comment: somthing like this would work replacing x by your regex match or whatever
  if(stringToWrite == 'x') rl.output.write('\u001b[34m'+stringToWrite+'\x1b[0m');
    else rl.output.write(stringToWrite)


https://repl.it/@belbalMehdi/Color-console#index.js

Comment: I've updated the question title and improved the answer with exact solution. Thanks, I would not be able to find this undocumented feature.

Answer (score -2):

If you mean the console, i can suggest the extension [Chalk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk).
Example using chalk:

```js
const chalk = require("chalk");

//...

console.log(chalk.red("Red text, ") + "normal text");
```

This will log "Red text, " in red.

Comment: I want to style the input not the output.